# Rails 4 Cocoon Gem + bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm working with **cocoon** for some nested fields and everything is perfect but I have an input where I need to save dates and I'm working with **bootstrap-datepicker-rails**, in the first form datepicker works fine but when I push for create a new form in the second form my datepicker stop working.

I was thinking in use cocoon function for resolve it, but I don't have knowledge in javascript so I'm doing something like that:

```
$('#order_payments').on('cocoon:before-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
     $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
```

But doesn't work what is the best way for resolve this problem ??

Thanks for your time !!

Answer (score 3):

Okay I could resolve the question my code is fine just I need to add **$(document).ready(function(){});** and inside put my cocoon function with the datepicker initializer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    $('#order_payments').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
       $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
});
```

I hope this code could help to someone!

Regards !

Comment: It might be useful to scope jquery search with `insertedItem.find('.datepicker').datepicker()`.

Comment: You made my day... Thanks